# Trouble with file upload using javascript swagger client and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swagger, swagger-codegen, react-dropzone

I have a problem with the source code generated by the Swagger codegen.
I want to upload a file with react. For this I have created a Dropzone and get a path to the file. If I use the generated client as it is in the documentation, it will not work. Unfortunately, the file is not sent. Only the file name. The debug console also does not show that binary data has been sent.

The request is not executed correctly. The file will not be uploaded. The parameter "file" is just the file name, instead of the binary data.

**Swagger-codegen version**

openapi-generator-cli-3.3.4.jar

**Swagger declaration file content**

Swagger .yaml:

```
  /orders/upload:
    post:
      operationId: "orderUploadPart"
      summary: "upload a textual or audio part of an order"
      tags:
        - "orders"
      description: "This funktion uploads a textual or audio part of an order to the sense.ai.tion cloud system. 
      The result is the resource identifier, that must be used in the order request."
      consumes:
        - multipart/form-data
      parameters:
        - in: "formData"
          name: "file"
          type: "file"
          required: true
          description: "the file to upload"
        - in: "formData"
          name: "media"
          type: "string"
          enum:
            - "text"
            - "wav"
            - "mp3"
          required: true
          description: "the media type of the the upload, can be ***text***, ***wav*** or ***mp3***"
```

Code:

```js
var apiInstance = new SenseaitionApi.OrdersApi();
var file = "/path/to/file"; // File | the file to upload
var media = "media_example"; // String | the media type of the the upload, can be ***text***, ***wav*** or ***mp3***
var callback = function(error, data, response) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } else {
    console.log('API called successfully. Returned data: ' + data);
  }
};
apiInstance.orderUploadPart(file, media, callback);
```

It's like in: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/samples/client/petstore/javascript/docs/PetApi.md#uploadFile

[Screenshot Chrome DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKW37.png)

**Command line used for generation**

`java -jar ${GOPATH}/bin/openapi-generator-cli.jar generate -i service_js_api.yaml -g javascript -o clients/javascript/senseaition-api-js -Dio.swagger.parser.util.RemoteUrl.trustAll=true`

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake. The documentation of generated Javascript code is wrong. For uploading a file (Javascript object) must be passed, not the Path.

This line is wrong:

```js
var file = "/path/to/file"; // File | the file to upload
```